# Formulas used to auto-populate Google Sheets calendar are working but have a major glitch

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm a very new Google Sheets user trying to learn some pretty advanced formulas to create productivity spreadsheets. In particular, I'm creating a goals spreadsheet that autopopulates a calendar: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1scwtbPLTFn4XTPgH7lQ4Is4jqiQ4NjofnWPIVP0F-8s/edit?usp=sharing.

The Goals sheet has action items that pull into the calendar based on dates. In my example link above, all the actions items I have listed are pulling successfully into the calendar. However, if you remove any action item from the Goals sheet, they all disappear on the calendar. I recreated the same formulas on a Test sheet (also in this spreadsheet), and everything seemed to be working, but for some reason, when I apply it to the larger Goals spreadhsheet, the formulas break down. It must be something in the way I have my formulas set up, but I can't figure out what the glitch is.

1. The action items are in multiple ranges on the Goals spreadsheet, so I'm currently using columns W,X and the QUERY function to pull them all into one single range. I've played with other ways to pull the data, as you'll see in the columns to the right of W,X, but for the moment, I'm just using W,X to pull data into the calendar.
2. The calendar then pulls all the values from W,X using the ARRAY_CONSTRAIN and FILTER functions.

If there's a another, and possibly simpler, way of doing this, I'd be so grateful to know. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Can you recreate/highlight this scenario of formula(s) breaking down in *Calendar* so that we can troubleshoot from that point on ?!

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is remove one of the action items in the Goals sheet to see that the items disappear in the calendar.

Comment: You mean to say the *action-items* needs to be saved in *Calendar* even when they are removed in *Goals* tab?!

Comment: No, the Calendar items should mirror the items in Goals. But if you remove one of the action items in the Goals sheet, EVERYTHING in the calendar disappears.

Comment: As an example lets say I removed `SPI Test 1` from *Goals* tab and it is subsequently removed from *Calendar* sheet as well for the date **July 3**. Can you explain what is the intended behaviour for this scenario ideally?! Also when I remove `SPI Test 1` in  *Goals*; only this action item seems to be removed from *Calendar*, yet you are quoting `EVERYTHING in the calendar disappears` which is confusing me!

Comment: Oh, man, I'm sorry. I guess it matters which one you remove. Try removing FAM Test 27 and FAM Test 28. And OUILA! They all disappear.

Comment: If possible do provide edit access to the sheet so that I can add in my formula from below so that you can test it out and finish this off!

Comment: I just made it editable.

Comment: I've pasted the single formula in **Cell_B6** in [`Calendar 2` tab here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1scwtbPLTFn4XTPgH7lQ4Is4jqiQ4NjofnWPIVP0F-8s/edit#gid=716973835). Also this formula does not need those helper columns(`W`, `X`) you created in the `Goals` tab

Comment: I see it! I tested it by removing some action items in the Goals tab, and it looks like it works! Sadly, when I change the date in H2, the formula breaks down.

Comment: Updated the formula. Please do test it out.

Comment: If you choose June 5, you'll see some odd things happening. I really appreciate your efforts to make this work, but I hate to take up any more of your time.

Comment: Updated the formula for you to test out

Comment: I think it works! Wow! I'll keep testing it, but no issues so far. Thanks so much! I wish I understood the formula you used. :) What's your background, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this formula in `Cell_B6` of `Calendar` tab. the formula directly looks into the range `H17:R` of `Goals` tab to match the date & pull action-items.*

`Important:` *Make sure to **clear all the cells within the range** `B6:H` of `Calendar` tab prior to pasting the formula so as for the formula-data to expand freely sideways+downside*

```js
=let(Σ,reduce(torow(,1),sequence(1,35,H2,1),lambda(a,c,ifna(hstack(a,vstack(c,array_constrain(tocol(index(if(Goals!H17:R=c,Goals!G17:Q,)),1,1),7,1)))))),
       reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(5,1,1,7),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,choosecols(Σ,sequence(7,1,c,1)))))))
```

[image]

***Updated formula:***

```js
=let(Σ,reduce(torow(,1),sequence(1,35,H2,1),lambda(a,c,ifna(hstack(a,let(Λ,tocol(index(if(Goals!H17:R=c,Goals!G17:Q,)),1,1),vstack(c,Λ,wrapcols(,7-counta(Λ),))))))),
       reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(5,1,1,7),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,choosecols(Σ,sequence(7,1,c,1)))))))
```

***Updated formula 2:***

```js
=let(Σ,reduce(torow(,1),sequence(1,35,H2,1),lambda(a,c,ifna(hstack(a,let(Λ,tocol(index(if(Goals!H17:R=c,Goals!G17:Q,)),1,1),vstack(c,array_constrain(Λ,7,1),iferror(wrapcols(,7-counta(Λ),),tocol(,1)))))))),
       reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(5,1,1,7),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,choosecols(Σ,sequence(7,1,c,1)))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm unfamiliar with the functions you're using, but I'll try it!

Comment: Did you mean that I should paste it into B7? B6 is a date cell. I cleared all cells and pasted your formula into B7, but I receive the following error: "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B14." B14 is another date cell.

Comment: Just ***absolutely clear everything*** from `B6:H45` cells (including dates and all) and then paste the above formula in ***B6*** Cell for it to work...